# Appending to DOM with AJAX, data displaying as string instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am trying to append data retrieved via an AJAX request to the DOM so I can grab it and put it into an array. However, when I append the data into the DOM it displays as a string instead of HTML. My code appending to the DOM is below, thanks!

```
var url = "https://xxxxxxx.com";
var $storeData = document.getElementById("data");

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var checkins = data.response.venues[0].stats.checkinsCount;
    var formattedCheckins = Number(checkins);
    $storeData.append('<p class="getData">' + formattedCheckins + '</p>')
});
```

I have tried this using `JSON.stringify` on the `formattedCheckins` variable as well to similar results. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `document.getElementById` is returning a native DOM Element. Using the `append()` method of that object places text within the element, not HTML. You seem to be confusing this with jQuery's `append()` method which does add HTML.

To solve this, select the `#data` element using jQuery instead:

```js
var $storeData = $("#data");

var formattedCheckins = 12345;
$storeData.append('<p class="getData">' + formattedCheckins + '</p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery, try `var $storeData = $("#data");` instead.

`document.getElementById` returns a DOM Object.

`var storeData = $('#data')` returns a jQuery Object.